# discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "rank" is not found

Tags: python, discord.py, bots

Im not sure if its that I am trying to call a decorator and its not returning. I know the problem is on the second or third line.

```
@commands.command()

async def rank(self, ctx, rank):
    await ctx.send(rank)

    if ctx.channel.id == bot_channel:
        stats = leveling.find_one({"id" : ctx.author.id})
        if stats is None:
            embed = discord.Embed(description="You have't sent any messages, no rank!!!")
            await ctx.channel.send(embed=embed)
        else:
            xp = stats["xp"]
            lvl = 0
            rank = 0
            while True:
                if xp < ((50*(lvl**2))+(50*lvl)):
                    break
                lvl += 1
                xp -= (50 * (lvl - 1) ** 2) + (50 * (lvl - 1))
                boxes = int((xp/(200*((1/2) * lvl))*20))
                rankings = leveling.find().sort("xp",-1)
                for x in rankings:
                    rank += 1
                    if stats["id"] == x["id"]:
                        break
                embed = discord.Embed(title="{}'s level stats".format(ctx.author.name))
                embed.add_field(name="Name", value=ctx.author.mention, inline=True)
                embed.add_field(name="XP", value=f"{xp}/{int(200*((1/2)*lvl))}", inline=True)
                embed.add_field(name="Rank", value=f"{rank}/{ctx.guild.member_count}", inline=True)
                embed.add_field(name="Progress Bar [lvl", value=boxes * ":blue_square:" + (20-boxes) * ":white_large_square", inline=False)
                embed.set_thumbnail(url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
                await ctx.channel.send(embed=embed)"
```

Comment: It is not good practice to have a parameter named the same as your function.  Did you add this command to a bot?

Comment: yes, it supposed to call when I do !rank command

Comment: Can you include the full error message - the stack trace - in your post? Otherwise it's hard to help.

Comment: What I mean is, as I read it, you have to call `bot.add(rank)` to add the command to your bot.  It has to be registered somehow.

Comment: Also, is it possible to show the whole file? Just so we have some context on `commands`.

Answer (score 0):

Usually restarting your bot fixes that problem; however, if it persists, double check that you don't have the command in *both* the index and a cog